# Getting website is being blocked when trying to access my web service in .net

Tags: .net, web-services, security, windows-server-2008, asmx

I have asmx file with GetData webmethod on my test server.

When I login to **test server** (I am Administrator) and run my method, everything works fine:

> http://localhost/app/Services.asmx?op=GetData

As a result I get string formatted as JSON data.

But, when I log in to **production server** and do the same, I get message:

**Content from the website listed below is being blocked by the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration.**

Both servers are Windows Server 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1.

I could't find any differences between Internet Security Settings on production vs. test server.

Any ideas where to look at?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried running it on different browser in the production?

Comment: I didn't. I am not allowed to install anything. The only thing I have is another server that has identical OS and settings and this one doesn't have any issues with my web service.

Comment: Did you ever fixed this issue?

Answer (score -1):

you need to add the following to your web.config

```
 <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
```

The url that you mentioned is by default blocked in the production server.